# grouped style not working for UITableView

Tags: uitableview, grouped-table

I have a split view app, created by adding a Split View Controller to a storyboard. I have a table view that is supposed to be grouped, with the rounded corners and gray background, but it's showing up plain style. I initialize the view in the app delegate like this:

```
self.dateController = [[DateViewController alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Where DateViewController is my custom TableViewController class. Here's the relative code in DateViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 260, 768, 764 )];
        toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 768, 44 )];
        [self.view addSubview: toolbar];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section {
    return 3;
}
```

What could be causing my table view not to be grouped? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer! I was overriding the wrong init function. I used this code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

And now it works!